# Calculate results based on multiplying previous row column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have spent some time to figure out the solutions using lag functionality as well as max functions. But this works fine when the operation is a sum or diff and not for multiplication.

Below is the original table:

```
id  a   b       c
1   100 0.02    0
2       0.030   0
3       0.040   0
4       0.05    0
```

Expected result:

```
id  a   b       c
1   100 0.02    102
2       0.030   105.06
3       0.040   109.2624
4       0.05    114.72552
```

Where c is

```
case when id =1 then (a + a*b)
else prev row of c(Lag c) +prev row of c(Lag c) * b
```

exception for id = 1:

```
c = (a + a*b)= 100 +100*0.02  = 102
```

id = 2:

```
c = 102 +102*0.03  = 105.06
```

id = 3:

```
c = 105.06 +105.06*0.04  = 109.2624
```

Tried multiple queries using lag and max functions. Able to do this easily in excel unlike sql.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: @Prats . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Sure.. I was trying to do this in Oracle Database.

Answer (score 2):

One method is a recursive CTE.  Another method is to implement a `PRODUCT()` window function.  Fortunately, you can do this using some arithmetic.

So, the multiplication factor is:

```
select t.*,
       exp(sum(log(1 + b)) over (order by id)) as factor
from t;
```

We can then do the complete arithmetic as:

```
select t.*,
       max(a) over () * exp(sum(log(1 + b)) over (order by id)) as c
from t;
```

As written, this should work in both Oracle and SQL Server, your original tags.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/12491) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @ Gordon: Wow!! Thank you so much for solving this :)
This query works like a charm..

Comment: This approach is really good but does not work with big numbers like when a= 978386.37
May be need to try another approach..

Comment: @Prats . . . I see nothing wrong with larger values, assuming they fit in the the range of values you want.  Perhaps you need to convert it to a floating point representation.  Oracles `number` format should be fine for this.

Answer (score -1):

**Sum:**

```
--drop table test

create table test(
  id numeric identity(1,1)
 ,a numeric
 ,b numeric
)

insert into test (a,b)values(100, 2)
insert into test (a,b)values(null,  3)
insert into test (a,b)values(null,  4)
insert into test (a,b)values(null,  5)

select id, a, b,
SUM( case when id = (select top 1 id from test) then (a+b) else b end) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as result
from test
```

[image]

**Multiplication:**

```
select id, a, b,
 exp(SUM( case when id = (select top 1 id from test) then log(a*b) else log(b) end) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) as result
from test
```

[image]